# Find the sum of this series for $k=1$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation

I am studying for my exam and came across this question but I am stuck, can someone tell me if I solved this question correctly? 
    $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}({k^3-(k-1)^3})$$
I know that if I plug in zero, I know that I end up with: $$a_0=0^3-\left(0-1\right)^3=1$$

then: $$=1+\sum _{k=1}^nk^3-\left(k-1\right)^3$$
and then finally I do some quick maths to end up with: $$=1+n^3$$

Comment: telescoping series, looks good to me

Comment: @gt6989b thank you, I appreciate it

Comment: In the title, did you mean for $k=1$ to $\mathbb n$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The series begins from $1$, hence we shouldn't start from $0$.

Via telescoping sum, the answer is $n^3$.

Comment: Oh yes, that's true, thank you.